# JAVA : Error: Could not find or load main class Tutorial Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Tutorial

Tags: java, visual-studio, intellij-idea

[image: Llevo meses con este problema]

Llevo meses con el problema que no se ha podido encontrar la clase Main en mis programas, cualquier tipo de codigo, desde el mas simple como un hola mundo, hasta el mas complejo.

He intentado en distintos IDES, como Visual Studio Code como en Intellij, pero siempre arroja el mismo error.

Puedo decir que he revisado variables de entorno, instalaciones y demas.

Comment: Mira [ask] y el [tour] para que tu pregunta no termine cerrada.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que el nombre del archivo es el nombre de la clase, entonces lo que puede estar sucediendo es que no tienes definido el path de tu JDK definido en las variables de entorno, asì que debes agregarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En las variables del sistema, primero revisa si tienes definida la ruta de JDK, si no existe, edita el valor de la variable path, agregando tambièn la ruta de tu JDK, por ejemplo en mi caso se encuentra en:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\bin
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]